# keep helper under mouse when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement something very close to what the 'Sortable Widget' would do, though I can't use it because of other things that doesn't work with the premade widget. 
So I'm trying to recreate it's functionality with draggable and droppable elements:

```
$(".Element").draggable({
    helper: 'original',
    drag: function(event, ui) {

        ElementWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);
        if($(this).prev().length){
            LeftElementWidth = $(this).prev().outerWidth(true);
            LeftElementLeftOffset = $(this).prev().offset().left;
            if(parseFloat(ui.offset.left+(ElementWidth/2)) < parseFloat(LeftElementLeftOffset+(LeftElementWidth/2))){
                $(this).prev().before($(this));
            }
        }

        if($(this).next().length){
            RightElementWidth = $(this).next().outerWidth(true);
            RightElementLeftOffset = $(this).next().offset().left;
            if(parseFloat(ui.offset.left+(ElementWidth/2)) > parseFloat(RightElementLeftOffset+(RightElementWidth/2))){
                $(this).next().after($(this));
            }
        }
    }
}); 

$("#Container").droppable({ accept: '.Element' });
```

It works fine, except for that the draggable-helper doesn't stay underneath the mouse-cursor when I move it's element to the next position.
Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5qFhg/15/

You'll see what happens when you try to sort the green boxes. How can I keep the helper in position?

Comment: You say you don't want the "Sortable Widget" but you decided to go with "draggable" & "droppable" elements... Why don't you use the "sortable" element with some custom behaviors then?  [jQuery UI : Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Comment: Yeah what exactly is stopping you from using the sortable widget?  Also do you want to be able to move these boxes vertically and outside of the red box.  Do you want them to snap into the empty space on moue up?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/margaret_/XM6f8/1/

Is this what you are looking for? Are you okay with using knockout? I can't add comments 'cause I don't have 50 reputation.

```
<a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: function() { viewModel.selectTask($data); },     visible: $data !== viewModel.selectedTask()"></a>
<input data-bind="value: name, visibleAndSelect: $data === viewModel.selectedTask(), event: { blur: function() { viewModel.selectTask(''); } }" />
```

Use parent and previous location to mimic the function.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    $(element).data("sortList", valueAccessor()); //attach meta-data
    $(element).sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            //track the original position of the element
            var parent = ui.item.parent();
            var prev = ui.item.prev();
            //create a function to move it back (if it has a prev sibling, insert after it, otherwise put it at the beginning)
            ui.item.moveItemBack = prev.length ? function() { ui.item.insertAfter(prev); } : function() { parent.prepend(ui.item); };
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var item = ui.item.data("sortItem");
            if (item) {
                //identify parents
                var originalParent = ui.item.data("parentList");
                var newParent = ui.item.parent().data("sortList");

                //figure out its new position
                var position = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(ui.item.parent().children(), ui.item[0]);

                if (position >= 0) {
                    //move the element back to its original position and let KO handle adding it to the new parent
                    if (originalParent !== newParent) {
                        ui.item.moveItemBack();
                    }

                    //place item in the proper position
                    newParent.remove(item);
                    newParent.splice(position, 0, item);
                }
            }
        },
        connectWith: '.container'
    });
}
```

Do you want the divs to appear side by side?